# how to minify html templates using angular2 and webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, minify

I am using the webpack starter from here:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

In webpack config, there is such code (I added minify options myself)

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/index.html', chunksSortMode: 'none',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
        // removeTagWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
      }  }),
```

and it minifies index.html file. But there will be many other html files as angular 2 templates in the project. How to minify them?

Other html files I saw are compiled into a javascript file - main.bundle.js

I hope it is possible with webpack. If not maybe there is some other tool?

**Update**

I checked https://github.com/bestander/html-minify-loader which uses https://github.com/Swaagie/minimize and here is what it writes:

> Minimize does not parse inline PHP or raw template files. Templates
>   are not valid HTML and this is outside the scope of the minimize. The
>   output of the templaters should be parsed and minified.

So for me will not work as I understand, because they are angular 2 templates.

Comment: For templates you can use `html-minify-loader` ( https://github.com/bestander/html-minify-loader )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need templates minification on prod, you should add code below in `webpack.prod.config.js` [(line 109)](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/webpack.prod.config.js#L109):

```
loaders: ['raw-loader', 'html-minify-loader'],
```

install `html-minify-loader` loader:

```
npm install html-minify-loader --save-dev
```

and add specify minify options as [described in docs](https://github.com/bestander/html-minify-loader):

```
 'html-minify-loader': {
     empty: true,        // KEEP empty attributes
     cdata: true,        // KEEP CDATA from scripts
     comments: true,     // KEEP comments
     dom: { // options of !(htmlparser2)[https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2]
      lowerCaseAttributeNames: false, // do not call .toLowerCase for each attribute name (Angular2 use camelCase attributes)
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, you are awesome. I thought this will not work, but since you wrote, I tried and it does. I am not sure why but also without minify options it removes the spaces from the html.

Comment: Whitespaces are removed with default options: https://github.com/Swaagie/minimize